# How to Support 64-bit architectures for sdk 28+?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, 64-bit

I’m updating an app in google play store to support **64-bit architectures**, when I generate the apk file targeting the **SDK 28+** Google Play developer console doesn’t accept the update with the error message that **the app is not compliant with the 64-bit policy** if I put "maxSdkVersion 27" in `build.gradle` file the update is accepted, when I inspect the apk file I find the same `*.so` file for all architectures `"armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a", "x86" and "x86_64",` any idea?

I have tried this instruction from google https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit, but it doesn’t help.

my lib folder structure:

[my lib folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rzRu.jpg)

EDIT 1: my gradle file

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'http://swisscodemonkeys.github.io/appbrain-sdk/maven'
    }

}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "xxx.xxx.xxx.com"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        maxSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 13
        versionName "31.08.19"
        multiDexEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [appPackageName: "${applicationId}"]
        renderscriptTargetApi 28
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true


           }

    dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        preDexLibraries true

            }

    buildTypes {

        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }


    }
  packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/*/libRSSupport.so'
        exclude 'lib/*/librsjni.so'
        exclude 'lib/*/librsjni_androidx.so'
        exclude 'lib/*/libblasV8.so'
        exclude 'lib/*/librs.channel.so'
        exclude 'lib/*/librs.uvencode.so'
    }

}



dependencies {
    //compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation project(':gpuimage')
    implementation project(':magicFilter')
    implementation 'com.appbrain:appbrain-sdk:+@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.+'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:28+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.+'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'it.neokree:MaterialNavigationDrawer:1.3.3'
    implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.3.+'
    implementation 'io.github.silvaren:easyrs:0.5.3'
    implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0-rc1'
    implementation 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.easing:library:2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:2.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.intuit.sdp:sdp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.intuit.ssp:ssp-android:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.6.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.9.0@aar') { transitive = true }
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.8.3@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:3.0.1.0.original@aar'
    implementation 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.7.0.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.sherazkhilji.videffects:videffects:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'
    implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.Cutta:GifView:1.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: post your build.gradle file, please.

Comment: hi Rakesh your solution doesn't work

Comment: @MrabtiPERPIXELSOFTWARES, Did you defined those `.so` files on gradle?